# Why do my UVs have circular shapes, in a square object?

Tags: uv

I'm trying to reset my UVs so I can UV Map my Asset. Can someone explain why it looks like this?
[image: object and UV layout]

Comment: You have n-gons faces in the mesh thats why you have distorted unwrap

Comment: I'm new, can you explain what I need to do to fix this? It was working earlier something I did along the way messed it up